# Database Engine Architecture books?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, database

I couldn't find any question similar to this one, I wanted to know about any books related to how database engines work internally. Kind of a "dragon book" about database engines, if you will.

I'm watching this video on MongoDB, and it got me interested in the inner workings of database engines and their architectures.

[**MongoDB, High-Performance SQL-Free Database**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFp9pZ6U0PE)

Comment: this is very informative topic, why close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one?
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/mysql/0596009577
Chapter ten is about storage engines. It's probably most about different types of storage engines but it should be something of value there.

Comment: I'm probably looking for something more oriented to `No-SQL`, since that's guaranteed to talk about `SQL`, but not the other way around..

Comment: Hm, I thought so. It's hard to find something like that though, but you already know that :)

Comment: Inner working of NoSql database is not all that different from RDBMS.  Principal behind things like indexes and journaling are pretty much the same.